# Rename directory in Bash script when the file with this name already exist

Tags: bash, shell, mv

Create example:

```
cd ~
mkdir .example.d
touch .example
```

Now we have one dir and one file.

Next:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv .example.d .example
```

> mv: cannot overwrite non-directory '.example' with directory
>   `.example.d'

How to solve the problem via bash script?
I need '.example' dir and '.example' file.

Answer (score 1):

Well unfortunately having a file and a folder bearing the same name in the same containing folder is not possible.

> This is because in Linux and Unix Files and folders are regarded as
>   Files unlike our perspective of files and folders.

As per the Linux/Unix filenaming conventions you cannot have two files of the same name in the same directory. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a file and a directory with the same name.

(The same way you cannot have two files, or two directories with the same name.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to [clobber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobber) the file with a directory?

If you are then unfortunately `mv` will not allow you to do this.  That's because it can't change a file [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) to a directory inode.

If you want to do this in a script then you must check for the file first and remove it if it exists.

Either with:

```
if [ -e .example ] ; then
    # Will remove existing directories
    rm -r .example
fi
mv .example.d .example
```

Or paying special attention as to weather the existing `.example` is a file or directory:

```
if [ -e .example -a ! -d .example ] ; then
    # Will not remove existing directories
    rm .example
fi
mv .example.d .example
```